# C#: Convert 3 Variables into 24 Hours Format

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm new to C# and i need help on converting 3 int variables into 24 hour format. I look on other Stack Overflow questions but it mostly only convert 1 variable into DateTime meanwhile i need to convert 3 variables into to 24 hour format. Here's what the variable looks like

```
private int hours = 1;
private int minutes = 1;
private int seconds = 1;
```

my expected outcome is `01:01:01` but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Create a DateTime variable with those values (see datetime constructors) then convert it back to a string using the ToString overload that allows you to specify the output required

Comment: Have you tried creating a single variable out of your three? Merging them to a single string etc. And then converting.

Comment: Maybe you should use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`. `var ts = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);`

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderPetrov, i think your answer is the simplest way to solve my problem, but i got a new problem, `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Index.hours' [FrontEnd]`. I cannot insert the variables into the TimeSpan constructor although if i enter a number directly it works. This problem also occurs for the other 2 answers.

Comment: Don't ask in the comments. Ask a new question by creating a new topic.

Comment: i already found the solution for that. I don't really need to use `TimeSpan` for my expected result. I just use `hours.ToString("00")` to convert a single number like 1 into 01 in string.

Comment: Don't write an answer in the comments. Write a normal answer and accept it.

Comment: ah yes, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var dt= new DateTime(1, 1, 1, hours, minutes, seconds); // year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds
```

If you want to cast to string after that, you can do:

```
dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // 01:01:01 // 24 hour clock digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"); // 01:01:01 AM // 12 hour clock
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found a answer that works for me since i can't insert the variables like the previous 2 answers. So i just use

```
hours.ToString("00")
minutes.ToString("00")
seconds.ToString("00")
```

this makes it into a string in 2 digit number like my expected outcome.